# Test not working in truffle

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, truffle, blockchain

Got his error when run truffle test

```
Using network 'test'.

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\test\TestFirst.sol
> Compilation warnings encountered:

    /D/Truffle Projects/statevariables/contracts/First.sol:21:6: Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
     function getAge4() public view returns (int) {
     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

> Artifacts written to C:\Users\92311\AppData\Local\Temp\test--9552-BsbV54PdVc1Y
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

  TestFirst
    1) testAge
    > No events were emitted
 
  0 passing (20s)
  1 failing

  1) TestFirst
       testAge:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\92311\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\testing\SolidityTest.js:92:1)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

My code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract First {
    int internal age = 40;
    int public age1 = 50;
    int private age2 = 60;
    int public constant age3 = 70;

    function getAge1() public view returns (int) {
        return age;
    }

     function getAge2() public view returns (int) {
        return age1;
    }

     function getAge3() public view returns (int) {
        return age2;
    }

     function getAge4() public view returns (int) {
        return age3;
    }
}
```

Test file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/First.sol";

contract TestFirst {
    function testAge() public {
        First meta = First(DeployedAddresses.First());
        meta.getAge1();
        Assert.equal(meta.getAge1(), 40, "Age 1 is not equal to 40");
    }
    
}
```

Version:

```
Truffle v5.2.4 (core: 5.2.4)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.16.0
Web3.js v1.2.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method getAge4() is not needed, because the attribute age4 is public.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract First {
    int internal age1 = 40;
    int public age2 = 50;
    int private age3 = 60;
    int public constant age4 = 70;

    function getAge1() public view returns (int) {
        return age1;
    }

    function getAge2() public view returns (int) {
        return age2;
    }

    function getAge3() public view returns (int) {
        return age3;
    }

}
```

*By the way, the constant name should be in capitalised SNAKE_CASE.*

Improved test cases

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "../contracts/First.sol";

contract TestFirst {

    First private first;

    address private owner;

    constructor() public {
        first = new First();
        owner = address(this);
    }

    function testAge1() public {
        Assert.equal(first.getAge1(), 40, "Age 1 is not equal to 40");
    }

    function testAge2() public {
        Assert.equal(first.getAge2(), 50, "Age 2 is not equal to 50");
    }

    function testAge3() public {
        Assert.equal(first.getAge3(), 60, "Age 3 is not equal to 60");
    }

    function testAge4() public {
        Assert.equal(first.age4(), 70, "Age 4 is not equal to 70");
    }

}
```

Expected result

```
$ truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/First.sol
> Artifacts written to /Users/markus/Projects/IntelliJ/cbc/contracts/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.17+commit.d19bba13.Emscripten.clang



$ truffle test   
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./test/FirstTest.sol
> Artifacts written to /var/folders/21/bjywjj2j1k34ctd61czlz_gc0000gn/T/test--6570-S6arXx4xH1b8
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.17+commit.d19bba13.Emscripten.clang

development


  TestFirst
    ✓ testAge1 (125ms)
    ✓ testAge2 (56ms)
    ✓ testAge3 (60ms)
    ✓ testAge4 (58ms)


  4 passing (6s)
```

Comment: "Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.2+commit.661d1103.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version" I'm getting this error.

Comment: My contract is getting compiled but when i run truffle test it shows;                                                           Compiling your contracts...
> Compiling .\test\TestFirst.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\92311\AppData\Local\Temp\test--12308-8u2MBlQzBDJj
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang
  TestFirst
    1) testAge
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (19s)
  1 failing

  1) TestFirst
       testAge:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Comment: Be aware that the import "truffle/Assert.sol" is different in my version and there is a different solitary version used in the test case.

Comment: Sir it's my second day that I have started learning solidity and I'm using vs code. Can you tell which compiler version should I use

Comment: Currently Compiler installed is V0.5.16 (solc-js) so which version should i mention in my projects and tests ?

Comment: In principle it is a good idea to use always the newest compiler versions - new features and security fixes. Quite often in tutorials you find old versions, but use the new once. The newest version today is 0.8.2 (12 days ago).